# JQUERY + sign keep on adding on typing backspace key

Tags: javascript, jquery

Running below HTML and JS code to get value from JSON and render itself input field. Rendering and display works fine.

But when i try to edit the number, +90 98888222 (example) exists.. on typing backspace key, it repeatedly adding + sign. ex: +++++90 98888222. On each press of backspace, it adds the + sign.

This code in get function only causing the issue i think. Need to add + sign manually it front as JSON data response without + sign.

return CONTACT_MOBILE ? '+' + CONTACT_MOBILE.number : '';

Not sure how to block with 1 + when typing backspace.

Thanks

```
get: function() {
   let CONTACT_MOBILE = _.find(this.updateProfile.contactList, (contact) => {
     return contact.type == 'MOBILE';
   });
   return CONTACT_MOBILE ? '+' + CONTACT_MOBILE.number : '';
},
set: function(newValue) {
  let CONTACT_MOBILE = _.find(this.updateProfile.contactList, (contact) => {
     return contact.type == 'MOBILE';
  });
  if(CONTACT_MOBILE) {
     CONTACT_MOBILE.number = '+' + newValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: So detect if it is there before you add it....

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```js
set: function(newValue) {
    let CONTACT_MOBILE = _.find(this.updateProfile.contactList, (contact) => {
      return contact.type == 'MOBILE';
    });
    if(CONTACT_MOBILE) {
      CONTACT_MOBILE.number = "";
      if(!(newValue.charAt(0) === '+')){
         CONTACT_MOBILE.number = '+';
      }
      CONTACT_MOBILE.number += newValue;
   }
}
```